# how to sort multiple qr code in order with firebase ml kit

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, firebase-mlkit

i have android app that reading multiple qr barcode in real time.
it can read barcodes at onece though , cannot read what number it is.

is there any way to sort multiple qr barcode in correct number order using firebase ml kit ?
is there method like zxing's "result.getRawBytes()" to get header data that includes number of the barcode ?

sorry for my poor english
thank you for reading

Comment: The available fields and methods are listed [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/barcode/FirebaseVisionBarcode).

Comment: thanks fo comment.i laready read that documentation though there's no way.also nothing has found in firebase other pages.but there's some app that can do what i want to , so i wish someone knows something about this question.

Comment: i send this to firebase support and they received my request so maybe someday this feature is added .anyway , i should use zxing instead of firebase for now.